# Include shared object in CMake

Tags: cmake, shared

I have a shared object called my-shared.so

I want to include it in my CMake build, without installing it, just linking the path. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CMakeLists.txt import library by:

```
add_library(myProjct SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(myProjct PROPERTIES
      IMPORTED_LOCATION /some/path/mylib/my-shared.so
)
```